Please help me identify my Dad's bike collection (80's-2000's)
My Dad was a mamil (middle aged man in lycra) in the 80's. He was an enthusiast and a collector and since he passed away in 2022, I have been slowly sorting through his many collections.
It feels like time to find new homes for his bikes.
I am hoping someone here can help me identify his bikes and give me some advice on where to find people who would be interested in restoring them.
Pictures of his Yellow Racer (serial number 9085) attached. I can tell he valued this one and thought others would too because he put the red paint on it to deter thieves (this was how he thought:)
Thanks in anticipation.
Sarah










Modolo is an Italian bicycle manufacturer brand.  You could even try to contact them directly. It uses Dura Ace component, so it was a relatively high-end bicycle. The Campagnolo brakes say BREV. INT., which is "short reach" but I do not know which model they are.

Thank you. I think the brakes are Modolo? The bike frame has markings around the flange that holds the handlebars that say Suntour Superbe Japan Road

The brake pad holders are Modolo, but the callipers are Campagnolo. The wheel hubs are Shimano Dura-Ace. The Suntour thing might be just the cap or the steerer, or who knows what. The pictures on the handlebars might be important to ID the bike brand.

AH!! This is great advice. thank you, I can try for some better pics of the handle bars. One side is quite clear but the other side (perhaps the side with some writing on it) is a little worn and harder to see.

Just added in a pic with some more detail from the handle bars, perhaps the letters say 'roue deposee' (wheel removed?)

I'd rather think that the last picture says marque déposée (registred trademark), but roue déposée was not a bad guess, given the wear marks.

I would not be surprised if he had this frame made for him by an artisan frame builder. It would be a good explaination of the poor finish, the mix of parts, the short serial no. and the personal value it held for him. Establishing who made the frame will likely be impossible unless you can interview his friends from that time

Just out of curiosity, can you tell whether the saddle logo says BROOKS or IDEALE?

Saddle says Brooks Professional @shoover

@Noise - i think you are right. A clever guy called Matt Calabro responded to a post i made on facebook saying he thinks its a Ken Evans bike https://kenevansframes.com.au/

@shoover I have two (different types of) Idealist saddles on other bikes. Are you interested in seeing them? Think i will need to make another post to share more pics

This bike costs nothing. Just try to give it away. Maybe somebody will make city bike using parts of this bike.

@user86512, you might well be wrong there, the trick is to find the person who will pay for it.

I thought I would expand on my comment.
The bike has a mixture of top-end parts from different top manufacturers of the era. These could have been chosen to go with each other for a "custom build" best performance or parts could have been changed over time, which given all are a similar age seems less likely.
The frame does not appear to have its original paint
The frame has a very low serial number, and is a steel lugged construction.
The bike was viewed as something special by the owner
All of the above lead me to think it's a hand-built frame from a small artisan framebuilder and was quite possibly built specifically for your father.
You have come back and said that a user on another forum has identified it as a Ken Evans bike: kenevansframes.com.au
It is expensive to have a frame made by a specialist frame builder and the result is often one of the best bikes many riders will have ever had. The bike is outfitted with some of the most expensive parts of its era.  In the modern world, the parts still have value (to collectors or retro enthusiasts), but not so much together as "we modern folk" like to have a groupset all of the same manufacturer. The frame with such poor paint hasn't much monetary value right now, but someone who wants a Ken Evans or an artisan quality frame would consider the cost of having this frame repainted properly worthwhile, so it still has value in the sense that there are people who consider this type of frame worth investing in.
You may wish to approach Ken Evans with detail photos of the frame joints etc to get a confirmation that it is in fact one of his.

thanks @noise  really appreciate your expertise and summary

My guess is that it's a bike made up of a variety of parts that does not represent any model of bike from a manufacturer. A parts bike.
In the 80s European bike makers tended toward European parts and Japanese bike makers tended toward Japanese parts.
This bike has an interesting mix of mostly good parts from different makers and different countries. Italian brakes (with Italian brake shoes from a different parts maker), Japanese headset, cranks and hubs, Italian shift levers with Japanese front derailleur, British seat and a fork that appears to be a generic replacement of lower quality than the frame.
The frame has a nice, forged drop out and my guess is that "Campagnolo" or "Shimano" is stamped on it. That would give you a possible clue as to the frame being European (Campagnolo) or Japanese (Shimano). You might need to remove the rear wheel to see what is stamped on the drop out. Knowing this does not get you much closer to knowing the specific manufacturer who made the frame.
Collectors of bikes look for specific bikes from specific bike makers that are complete and in good condition. This bike is none of those things.
However, with some work and replacing of worn parts this can be a nice riding bike. I'd find someone who is interested in working on bikes and give it to him/her.

Thanks David, This is useful advice. I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I posted pics in a Facebook group and a fellow called Matt Calabro wrote
"I'm about 90% certain this is an old Ken Evans bike. High-end Australian frame building. The mix of campy, sugino and superbe is typical of earlier builds by him. Mid to late 70s. is there a stamp or serial the underside of the bottom bracket."
I have found Ken's website and think Matt is right. How knowledgeable he is! I am planning to email Ken and see if he knows anyone who would be up for the restoration project.

Not only that, but IIRC French parts would only work on French bikes, and then English and Italian were sometimes compatible.
